What are the materials needed for the first step in the construction of Hamikdash?
Many people mainly talk about red heifer.
But as far as I know, sacrificial offerings can only be offered once the temple is built, so shouldn't the Shamir be the main point rather than the red heifer?

Please explain: What do you believe is so essential about the shamir? - Anyway, it isn't really true that offerings can only be offered once the temple is built. We basically hold that the kedusha of the Mikdash is permanent, with or without a building.

See Eduyot 8:6 מקריבין אף על פי שאין בית we can offer sacrifices in the right spot even without the structure

Anyway, the Rambam writes (Beis Habechirah 1:8) that the Beis Hamikdash can be built of bricks, if stones aren't available. (Now, that does bring up the interesting question of whether Lego bricks are included too...)

I found this online and will include a link to the full discussion/shiur on the subject.  The construction of the Beit Hamikdosh happens according to the time/circumstances of its construction.  Since you used the words "needed for" and not "used in the construction" I am assuming you're referring to the one that hasn't yet been built - the 3rd one.  Here an explanation that Yisroel Bankier published 10 years ago on Mishna Yomit's site:
"The Tifferet Yisrael cites Rashi who explains that the third Beit HaMikdash will be built in shamayim without human input; so why is our understanding now necessary? One explanation is that the Rambam disagrees. The Rambam understands that the Midrash on which Rashi bases his comments is agada that is not to be understood literally. Instead the intention of the Midrash is that the divine assistance for the future human construction will be miraculous."
The full article can be found via this website link:
https://www.mishnahyomit.com/articles/Midot/Building%20the%20Third%20Beit%20HaMikdash
May your search and efforts bring us closer to the impending and miraculous "shipment" of our replacement!!
